# Как сделать casino на discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Здравствуйте хочу сделать код на казино использую библиотеку discord.py ,но у меня возникает ошибка бот выдаёт одно и тоже число! Как это исправить?

```
@commands.command(aliases = ['казино', 'c'])
    async def casino(self, ctx, amount: int = None):
        if self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})["balance"] <=0:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"__{ctx.author}__, у вас не достаточно средств"))
        else:
            eco = random.randrange(1,2)
            if eco == 1:
                emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(), description=f"Вы проиграли! Может быть вам повезёт в следующий раз!")
                await ctx.send(embed = emb)
                mone = self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})['balance'] - amount
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, 'user_id': ctx.author.id}, {'$set':{'balance':mone}})
            elif eco == 2:
                emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(),description=f"Вы выиграли! Ваша сумма была удвоенна!")
                await ctx.send(embed = emb)
                money = self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})['balance'] + amount*2
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, 'user_id': ctx.author.id}, {'$set':{'balance':money}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@commands.command(aliases = ['казино', 'c'])
async def casino(self, ctx, amount: int = None):
        if self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})["balance"] <=0:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"__{ctx.author}__, у вас не достаточно средств"))
        else:
            eco = random.choice([1, 2])
            if eco == 1:
                emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(), description=f"Вы проиграли! Может быть вам повезёт в следующий раз!")
                await ctx.send(embed = emb)
                mone = self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})['balance'] - amount
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, 'user_id': ctx.author.id}, {'$set':{'balance':mone}})
            elif eco == 2:
                emb = discord.Embed(title='Казино', color=discord.Color.blurple(),description=f"Вы выиграли! Ваша сумма была удвоенна!")
                await ctx.send(embed = emb)
                money = self.collection.find_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, "user_id": ctx.author.id})['balance'] + amount*2
                self.collection.update_one({'guild_id': ctx.guild.id, 'user_id': ctx.author.id}, {'$set':{'balance':money}})
```